# cannot seem to map a custom type using the latest autoMapper library in c#

Tags: automapper

I cannot seem to map a custom type using the latest autoMapper library in c#.  I am using the sample from the sample app but added a custom type.  Both classes are similar just the code names are different.  I do want this to be a "GlobalTypeConverter" as it used a few times.

The error is at validation: 
//Error: The following 1 properties on TestApp.Form1+Destination are not mapped: 
    mycode
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, or rename the property on TestApp.Form1+Source.

```
public class Source
{
  public string Value1 { get; set; }
  public string Value2 { get; set; }
  public string Value3 { get; set; }
  public standardCoding stdcode { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
  public int Value1 { get; set; }
  public DateTime Value2 { get; set; }
  public Type Value3 { get; set; }
  public myClass.code mycode { get; set; }
}

public class DateTimeTypeConverter : TypeConverter<string, DateTime>
{
  protected override DateTime ConvertCore(string source)
  {
    return System.Convert.ToDateTime(source);
  }
}

public class TypeTypeConverter : TypeConverter<string, Type>
{
  protected override Type ConvertCore(string source)
  {
    Type type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(source);
    return type;
  }
}

public class standardCodingConverter : TypeConverter<standardCoding, myClass.code>
{
  protected override myClass.code ConvertCore(standardCoding source)
  {
    var result = new myClass.code();
    result.CodingSystem = source.StandardCodingSystem;
    result.Description = source.StandardCodeDescription;
    result.value = source.StandardCode;
    return result;
  }
}


public void btnAutoMapperTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Mapper.CreateMap<string, int>().ConvertUsing(Convert.ToInt32);
  Mapper.CreateMap<string, DateTime>().ConvertUsing(new DateTimeTypeConverter());
  Mapper.CreateMap<string, Type>().ConvertUsing<TypeTypeConverter>();
  Mapper.CreateMap<standardCoding, myClass.code>().ConvertUsing(new standardCodingConverter());
  Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
  Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

  var newcode = new standardCoding();
  newcode.StandardCode = "123";
  newcode.StandardCodeDescription = "my desc";
  newcode.StandardCodingSystem = "CodeSys";

  var source = new Source
  {
    Value1 = "5",
    Value2 = "01/01/2000",
    Value3 = "AutoMapperSamples.GlobalTypeConverters.GlobalTypeConverters+Destination", 
    stdcode = newcode
  };




/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "cds_dt")]
public partial class standardCoding
{

private string standardCodingSystemField;

private string standardCodeField;

private string standardCodeDescriptionField;

/// <remarks/>
public string StandardCodingSystem
{
  get
  {
    return this.standardCodingSystemField;
  }
  set
  {
    this.standardCodingSystemField = value;
  }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "token")]
public string StandardCode
{
  get
  {
    return this.standardCodeField;
  }
  set
  {
    this.standardCodeField = value;
  }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "token")]
public string StandardCodeDescription
{
  get
  {
    return this.standardCodeDescriptionField;
  }
  set
  {
    this.standardCodeDescriptionField = value;
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by looking online (sample code "CustomValueResolvers.cs" did not work for me).

My one incorrect line was: 
...
.ForMember(src => src.DiagnosisCode, opt => opt.ResolveUsing() .FromMember(r => r.DiagnosisProcedureCode))